# Remove Last Character From String If It's a "!" Using For-Loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I have

```
function remove(s) {

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        let lastChar = s.slice(-1);

        if (lastChar === "!") {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
        }
        else {
            return s;
        }
    }
  return s;
}
```

And this is passing 105 tests but failing 1 on [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/exclamation-marks-series-number-2-remove-all-exclamation-marks-from-the-end-of-sentence/train/javascript).

The test that it's failing is:

`Expected: '\'isl\'', instead got: '\'isl!\''` for when (s) is `"isl!!!!!"`

I can't figure out why, in this case, it's not removing the last character in the string.

This should be removing the last character in the string whenever it's `!`:

```
if (lastChar === "!") {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
        }
```

I've also tried:

```
s = s.replace("!", "");
```

But same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Simplified using `String.replace` -- `s = s.replace(/!+$/g, '')`?

Comment: @31piy why does that work and `s = s.replace("!", "");` does not?

Comment: Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). It clearly says "If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced".

Comment: Right so then `s = s.replace(/!+$/g, '')` works when `i++` and  `s = s.replace("!", "");` works when `i--` - this is really the answer to my question. If you want to post an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You don't really need any loop when using `String.replace` method. If the excercise needs that you do it with a loop, then you should follow the approach suggested by T.J. Crowder (or others, whatever you prefer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@T.J. Crowder pointed me in the right direction, but he didn't provide an answer that followed my original logic (in this case I wanted to use a for-loop).

The key takeaway is that `s = s.replace("!", "");` will work when `i--` and `s = s.replace(/!+$/g, '')` will work when `i++`. Because, as far as I understand, the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method only replaces the first occurrence of the string, which is why we need `i--` to force the loop to iterate backwards through the string, making sure that every occurance of `"!"` gets replaced.

I.e. this will work:

```
function remove(s) {

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i--) {

        let lastChar = s.slice(-1);

        if (lastChar === "!") {
            s = s.replace("!", '')
        }
        else {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

And this will also work:

```
function remove(s) {

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        let lastChar = s.slice(-1);

        if (lastChar === "!") {
            s = s.replace(/!+$/g, '');
        }
        else {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595859/remove-last-character-from-string-if-its-a-using-for-loop-javascript?noredirect=1#comment97903938_55595859

Answer (score 3):

Because you're increasing `i` and checking `i < s.length` on each loop. At one point, you remove a `!` (thus shortening the string) and `i` is equal to `s.length` and you never check the last char.

There's no reason for `i` at all. (Or a `for` loop, but if that was the requirement in the challenge...)

If you step through it with your debugger, you'll see the problem. This version using `console.log` also shows the problem:

```js
function remove(s) {

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        let lastChar = s.slice(-1);

        if (lastChar === "!") {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
            console.log(`i = ${i}, s = '${s}', s.substring(i) = '${s.substring(i)}'`);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`returning '${s}'`);
            return s;
        }
    }
  console.log(`returning '${s}' at end, because ${i} >= ${s.length}`);
  return s;
}
remove("isl!!!!!");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Oh so I would have needed to decrease while looping `i--` instead of increasing.

Comment: @HappyHands31 - Well, again, `i` isn't doing anything useful for you in the loop. If you *have* to use a `for` loop, I'd use `for( ; s && s.slice(-1) === '!"; ) { s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1); }` but really that's a `while` in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using for loop.

```
const stringRemover (str) => {
  if (str[str.length-1] === "!") {
    return str.slice(0,str.length-1);
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand - this returns `isl!!!!` - only removes one "!" when there isn't a for-loop?

Comment: This works: `function remove(s) {
    return s.replace(/!+$/, '');
}` - but I don't understand how that's only removing the instances of "!" that are at the end of the string.

Comment: my bad i thought you want to last character to be removed only once.

Comment: last character must always be removed if it's a "!"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive function and check if the last char using `CharAt` if it is `!`. If it is so then again call the same function but with new string which is created after removing the last `!`

Not sure why the `for` is needed if the last character is needed

```js
function remove(str) {

  let getLastChar = str.charAt(str.length - 1);
  if (getLastChar === '!') {
    return remove(str.substring(0, str.length - 1))
  } else {
    return str;
  }

}

console.log(remove("isl!!!!!"));
```

Here is codewars result

Here is [image: codewars] result

Answer (score 0):

As answered in a previous reply, `i < s.length` is checked in every iteration in a `for` loop.
Try this :

```
function remove(s) {

    let a = s.length;

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {

        let lastChar = s.slice(-1);

        if (lastChar === "!") {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
        }
        else {
            return s;
        }
    }
  return s;
}
```